# Keep Voronoi texture look during Cell Fracture

Tags: texturing, materials, add-on, shaders

Say I have a UV sphere with a simple Voronoi texture

[image]

Now I run the Cell fracture add-on, and I get

[image]

We see that the old texture is applied individually for each cell, so the end result does not look like a fractured version of the old sphere. Is there any way to preserve the texture into each cell so that it globally looks like the old texture? Some approaches that come to mind are

- For example, a possibility would be to remove the shader from the cells, and then "project" the material from the original sphere (by scaling it up a little, perhaps). Is this doable?
- Another option would be e.g. to join the cells (in which case the original pattern is recovered, because the texture is applied to the joined object, which is essentially identical to the original sphere). Can we separate the cells again, this time preserving the texture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use UV coordinates.
After fracturing the UV map is separated for each 'shard' and the texture stays in place.

<sup>The main downside are 'seams' along the edges of the original UV map.</sup>
[image]

---

For seamless look:

Use an empty to  control the Voronoi texture :).

1. Add an *Empty* in the same place as your sphere
2. Change the *Texture coordinates* to *Object > Empty*
3. Now fracture your sphere, and the texture will stay the same

Now bake the result for each individual shard.

<sup>One solid sphere. One fractured sphere. Each has it's own empty, textures look the same</sup>
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice trick but unfortunately it doesn't quite work: as soon as I move a cell, its pattern is all messed up again. So it only works as long as the fractured cells stay in the exact same position as the original sphere (which kinda defeats the purpose of fracturing the object in the first place). Any idea how to "apply" the pattern so that it stays fixed if we move the pieces around?

Comment: Hey :). Sure. You need to bake the texture for those 'cell' objects, so it stays in place when you move them. It's called 'texture baking'.

Comment: I see. I guess this is a great time to learn how to bake textures ;-P Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey :). No need. If you use UV mapping, it works even with cell fracture. I'll edit the answer :).

Comment: Brilliant :: *kisses fingers* :: works like a charm. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help :). (those darn UV seams are the main reason I didn't suggest it at first). Anyways, good luck with your project.